Counting Possibilities for Multiple Independent 4-Question Patterns
I am a high schooler who fantasised this situation after my friend joked on seeing this pattern of BAC in every objective test. I want to calculate what is the probability of getting the pattern BAC in a 40-question range. It goes like this:
In a test, an objective question has selections of A, B, C or D.
Every four questions form a pattern of a random shuffle of 4 alphabets from ABCD, ranging from AAAA to DDDD.
Question 1
How many times does the sequence BAC appear in continuous order?
What is the probability of getting the sequence BAC?
My solution:
In a set of 4 questions, the number of trials is 4. In the first trial, there are 4 possible encounters, either A, B, C or D. In the second trial, each branch of alphabet, again, has 4 possible encounters. The same pattern occurs for third and fourth trials. Thus, an exponentiation function is used to calculate the total sample space:
$n(S) =4^4 = 256$
Getting BAC has 8 possible events
$ABAC$ $BBAC$ $CBAC$ $DBAC$ $BACA$ $BACB$ $BACC$ $BACD$
$n(BAC)= 8$
Thus, the probability of getting BAC in a set of 4 questions is
$P(BAC)= \frac{n(BAC)}{n(S)} = \frac{8}{256} = \frac{1}{32}$
Please double-check my answer.
Question 2
If the test has 40 questions, what is the probability of getting BAC? (Consider each set has the chance to merge coincidentally with its subsequent set to form BAC, e.g. a set that ends in BA and a subsequent set which starts with C)
Please solve question 2.
My Solution:
Refer to solution in Question 1, the probability for one set of four questions is $\frac{1}{32}$. In 40 questions, there are 10 sets of the same pattern.
Total number of sample space in 10 sets is 10 times the number of sample space in one set.
Thus, total sample space is
$n(S) = 256 \times 10 = 2560$
In every set, the event of getting BAC is the same. Total number of events of getting BAC in 10 sets is 10 times the number of events of getting BAC in one set.
Thus, total number of events of getting BAC is
$n(BAC) = 8 \times 10 = 80$
Thus, probability of getting BAC within 10 individual sets is
$\frac{80}{2560} = \frac{1}{32}$
In the merging of two sets, we can possibly get BA in the previous set and C in the subsequent set, or B in the previous set and AC in the subsequent set.
Case 1:
Previous: BA, Subsequent: C
In the first set, the event of getting BA at the end would be 16 times, in the following set, the event of getting C at the beginning would be 64 times.
Case 2:
Previous: B, Subsequent: AC
In the first set, the event of getting B at the end would be 64 times, in the following set, the event of getting C at the beginning would be 16 times.
Since case 1 and 2 have the same value for different situation, let's calculate their combined probability:
$P((BA,C)\cap(B,AC)) = (\frac{16}{256} \times \frac{64}{256}) + (\frac{64}{256} \times \frac{16}{256}) = 2(\frac{16}{256} \times \frac{64}{256}) = \frac{1}{32}$
The result we get is the intersection of the merge of any two sets. In total we have 10 sets, it means 9 merging happens:
Total probability of merging, $P(M)= \frac{1}{32} \times 9 = \frac{9}{32}$
Hence, let's conclude the probability of getting BAC,
P(BAC) = Probability of getting BAC within 10 individual sets + Probability of getting BAC in merging between 2 conjugate sets
$P(BAC) = \frac{1}{32} + \frac{9}{32} = \frac{5}{16}$
Please double-verify my solution. It'll be great if someone could explain to me how to tackle this question by reasoning and illustrate the picture in a whole, too.

Please edit your question to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

For question Q1, which is ambiguous as to the number of questions, I suggest assuming that there are exactly $~4n~$ questions, and then attacking the problem via Linearity of Expectation,
which includes a proof that the formula applies even when the events are not
independent of each other.  For Q2, one approach to computing the size of the favorable subset of $~4^{40}~$ elements is recursion.  ...see next comment

An alternative approach might be a simplified form of markov chain analysis, similar to what was used in this question.  In the linked question, see the "Sanity Checking - Method-2 : Probability-Oriented Recursion Analysis" section, near the end of the Part-2 answer.  In fact, I am on thin ice with respect to both of my Q2 suggestions.  ...see next comment

That is, I am unsure how practical either of these Q2 suggestions are.  The only other Q2 alternative that I can think of is Inclusion-Exclusion, which seems nightmarish here.

Note: re my previous comment, as to Q1: I was only focusing on the expected number of times that the sequence BAC occurs.  For the second part of Q1, which I ignored, this is actually covered in your Q2.

For Q2, my original thought is just to multiply the number of sample space and the number of the event of getting BAC by 10, and, in the end, still get the probability of 1/32. However, I realise it would not be a viable approach if consider two subsequent sets having the chance of merging together to form BAC, and thing gets more complicated.

Your $\frac1{32}$ for Q1 the probability ever seeing BAC in $4$ draws looks reasonable. I suspect the answer to Q2 for the probability of ever seeing BAC in $40$ draws is a more complicated rational $\frac{69626957585858113936519}{151115727451828646838272} \approx 0.4607525554$.
There are various approaches, but I think this is simplest to explain:

Let $p_n$ be the probability of ever seeing BAC in $n$ draws and $q_n=1-p_n$ the probability of not seeing BAC in $n$ draws.

$q_0=q_1=q_2=1$ as you do not have enough letters when $n<3$

$q_n=q_{n-1}-\frac1{64}q_{n-3}$ as you need to add a letter to a pattern that does not have BAC but exclude cases where the last three are BAC $\big($with conditional probability $\frac1{4^3}=\frac1{64}\big)$

So you run the recursion and get $q_3=0.984375,$ $q_4=0.96875,$ $q_5=0.953125,$ $q_6=0.937744140625,$ $q_7=0.922607421875, \ldots$. You need to go up to $q_{40} \approx 0.5392474446$. You can also use $q_n=\frac{a(n)}{4^n}$ where $a(n)$ is OEIS A099503.


But you want $p_n=1-q_n$,

Q1: $p_4=1-0.96875= 0.03125$
Q2: $p_{40}\approx 1-0.5392474446=0.4607525554$

